# Positive or negative infinity as default parameter in Haxe

Tags: parameters, constants, haxe

When I try to pass a default parameter from `Math` such as `POSITIVE_INFINITY` to a function, Haxe compiler gives an error that default values should be constant.

Example:

```
package;

class Test {
    public function new(time:Float = Math.POSITIVE_INFINITY) {
    }
}
```

Above gives the error:

> Parameter default value should be constant

In ActionScript, these could be implemented such as:

```
public function Test(time:Number = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY) { /* ... */ }
public function Test(time:Number = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY) { /* ... */ }
public function Test(time:Number = Number.MAX_VALUE) { /* ... */ }
public function Test(time:Number = Number.MIN_VALUE) { /* ... */ }
```

In Haxe, `Math.POSITIVE_INFINITY` is defined as:

```
/**
    A special Float constant which denotes negative infinity.
**/
static var POSITIVE_INFINITY(default,null) : Float;
```

As Haxe doesn't have constants, I presume a literal must be passed.  Or, is there a some combination of `inline` or `final` that would enable this method signature syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not doable at the moment.

I suggest opening a feature request since it really seems to be a legitimate use case.